# Retrieving eloquent relationship with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

When I try to get the name of the Category from my product, I discovered I had to use a 'C' rather than a 'c' before it retrieved results. However when I try to get the Supplier name, the lowercase s works just fine. I was wondering what is causing this difference. Also if I dd($var), is the relations field expected to be empty. I assumed it would have something related to the relationships defined in my models.

**Blade.php**

```
  <td>{{$product->Category->name}}</td>
     <td>{{$product->salePrice}}</td>
     <td>{{$product->stock}}</td>
 <td>{{$product->supplier->company_name}}</td>
```

**Product.php**

```
 public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category','category');
    }
 public function supplier()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Supplier','supplier_id');
    }
```

**Category.php**

```
public function product()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }
```

**Supplier.php**

```
public function product()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `_id` on your **Product** model:

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category','category_id');
}
```

Or leave empty

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
```

In your **Controller**

```
public function index()
{
  $products = Product::all()->with('category');
  return view('your_view', compact('products'));
}
```

If you `dd` the products
In your **View** you will se that the relation has been loaded because of the

[Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

> When accessing Eloquent relationships as properties, the relationship data is "lazy loaded". This means the relationship data is not actually loaded until you first access the property. However, Eloquent can "eager load" relationships at the time you query the parent model.

```
@foreach($products as $product)
<td>{{$product->category->name}}</td>
     <td>{{$product->salePrice}}</td>
     <td>{{$product->stock}}</td>
 <td>{{$product->supplier->company_name}}</td>
@endforeach
```

Comment: thank you for your response but the name of the column  being referenced is  category and not category_id so i don't think that is the issue